# Set MdiParent from a ShowDialog form

Tags: vb.net, forms, mdi

I've got a form, `frmEmail` which is called using `f.ShowDialog` (Where f is an instance of `frmEmail`).

How can I, when closing the form, open an instance of `frmOrder` but set `fOrder.MdiParent = frmMain`?

`frmMain` is my MDI form, `frmOrder` is a form I need to open, and `frmEmail` is the form I'm opening it from.

My code at the moment is

```
revoke = True

Dim f As New frmOrder(con, False, False, , orderNum)
f.MdiParent = ' Not sure what to put here?
f.Show()

Me.Close()
```

Do I need to pass in a variable that stores reference to `frmMain`? Is there another way to do it?

Obviously I can't use `f.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent`, because as I mentioned before, `frmEmail` is opened using `f.ShowDialog` so has no `MdiParent`.

Comment: This is a problem that has too many solutions.  Most obvious one is putting this code in the right place.  It belongs after the ShowDialog() call, executed only if it returns DialogResult.Ok.

Comment: @HansPassant I couldn't put it there because it was conditional whether or not it should re-open the `frmOrder`.

Comment: Sure, that is exactly why you have to check the return value of ShowDialog().  And close it properly, not with Close() but by assigning the Me.DialogResult property.  A dialog should *always* have a dialog result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still open a form in `ShowDialog` and set the "Owner" property.

Where you're opening `frmEmail`, instead of opening it like using `f.ShowDialog()`, use `f.ShowDialog(Me.MdiParent)` (If your MDI form is the parent of the form where you open `frmEmail`, otherwise just tweak it as relevant).

That way, when opening `frmOrder`, you set the `MdiParent` property to be `frmEmail`'s owner property.

```
Dim f As New frmOrder(con, False, False, , orderNum)
f.MdiParent = Me.Owner
f.Show()
```